# Self-deportation of American Citizens from US

Tags: united-states, immigration

It is conceivable that [US citizens detained at CBP](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/us-citizen-detained-by-ice-francisco-erwin-galicia-border-officials-conditions-bad-almost-self-deported/) will self deport to exit  overcrowded CBP detainment facilities avoid lengthy detainments (>20 days).  How would a US citizen's self-deportation affect one's ability to cross borders and return home?

## Update:

"Food for thought" for responses:

1. Upon deportation, why would CBP allow you to re-enter the country with the questioned documents?
2. Would CBP not confiscate the questioned documents before deportation?
3. Citizen is held incommuncado.

There is [a claim that 2 of 3 Americans live](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/43232/10793) in the `100-Mile border zone` patrolled by CBP:

[image]

Comment: Related: the UK forcibly deported citizens to Jamaica, and not all of them have managed to get back. Some died before the abuse could be rectified. https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/windrush-government-deportations-british-citizens-uk-caribbean-home-office-rudd-javid-a8501076.html

Answer (score 22):

### They can't take his citizenship...

Since he claims to be a born citizen, he has citizenship by birthright and nothing CBP can do can possibly revoke it.

He can [voluntarily renounce his citizenship](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/us-citizenship/Renunciation-US-Nationality-Abroad.html), but he has to do that through the State Dept. (which CBP is not part of).  And that is an elaborate and expensive process *that can't even be done inside the United States*. If someone could do it merely by entering without papers and asking for a self-deport, lots of expats would save a lot of money - and that's not gonna happen :)

### ...but they could put him to serious inconvenience

In this particular case, CBP found his documents suspect.  Probably because (if it's the case we've seen documented elsewhere) he was with two other people whose entry was illegal, and *they* had forged documents.

So most likely, if he agreed to self-deport, CBP would use that as *prima-facie* evidence that he is not a bona-fide citizen, and therefore, that his papers are faked. They certainly will not give fake papers back to someone who has tried to pass them.

So the victim would be obliged to go back to SSA, the state, etc. and re-acquire his identity documents.  From outside the country. It's a pretty big chore.

Comment: The citizen would be deported and have no papers?   Yikes!

Comment: They had forged documents *and his mother claimed he was not born in the US*.

Comment: Deported to where?

Comment: @gerrit In this case back to where his mother and sibling were from which was Mexico.

Comment: Indeed, I do not know for sure but I would be surprised if it were not necessary to sign a statement admitting to the grounds for the "self-deportation"; this could make it difficult to establish US citizenship to the satisfaction of the state department or DHS.

Comment: @phoog That wouldn't surprise me either, that they would pressure him to disavow the *particular* paper documents as fake. However Texas could issue him another copy of his birth certificate or DL, and SSA could issue another SS card.  Those would be new official documents, and DHS cannot assassinate those.  Since he can't enter, presumably these would go straight from issuer to DHS via a friend-of-the-court such as an attorney, so there would be a reasonable chain of evidence to show they are not forged.

Comment: @chrylis Wow, I didn't know *that*. But that makes sense given that the mom would want to keep custody and not have her son descend into DHS hell or a foster family. Anyway that is much worse for the family and makes DHS much less wrong here.

Comment: @Harper I suspect he'd have to sign a statement that he is not a US citizen (see the comments on the other answer).  That would be harder to correct than it would be to get a new birth certificate.

Comment: @phoog he could sign a paper saying he is DB Cooper.  If the facts don't support that statement, then it is worthless - the statement, not the facts. He could easily recant with the perfectly reasonable explanation that his mother had misinformed him.  Also, the State Department and IRS will have a big problem with CBP signing away his citizenship like that.

Comment: If I were hateful, I would earn some foreign income, pay US tax on it, then sue the Commissioner for the tax back, saying I shouldn't owe it since I am ruled not a citizen. Pull in CBP as a witness and let the judge give them what-for.

Comment: I am a little puzzled as to how any actions other than the citizen's drives the border crossing to return home.   If the citizen is in fact a citizen, is it not DHS responsibility to recognize authentic documentation when presented?

Comment: @gatorback in this particular case,  it was an inland stop and read all the commentary for just how screwed up this situation was.

Comment: I agree the "admission" of alienage would be legally worthless. But from a practical administrative point of view, assuming the person doesn't encounter a sympathetic or even reasonable officer of the Department of State or DHS, the document could cause problems.  Who knows: maybe signing the document and going to a consulate in Mexico would have led to the relatively prompt issue of a US passport.  But even still, if the CBP officers at the border had a record of the supposedly fraudulent birth certificate, they could conceivably find the passport to be fraudulent as well.

Answer (score 9):

He's a citizen; his citizenship can't be taken by ICE or CBP, and he can't legally be kept from returning to the US from Mexico by them. He was offered "self-deportation" because ICE was illegally or irrationally detaining him, thinking that his documents were forged or stolen.

He *could* have "self-deported" in order to simply get out of detention, since it was offered by ICE; but he's a US citizen, so as soon as he was in Mexico, he could simply go to the border and cross with his documents. If CBP kept him from crossing at the border, his lawyer could attest to his citizenship with documents. And any "self-deportation" document he signed could be shown to be meaningless in court, since he's a citizen, and ICE was illegally or irrationally detaining him.

Comment: Also, since he is not a Mexican citizen, Mexico would be under no obligation to allow him to enter their country, and it could deport him to the U.S. if it wished.

Comment: It strikes me that "simply" is probably not the term that applies to a border crossing after you've been deported as a non-citizen. Your biometrics would be on file as a person who has been deported, and it's not clear to me what travel documents you'd have (they presumably won't deport you and hand you your US passport on your way out the door). I'm not saying that you won't get back, but it's unlikely to be a simple process.

Comment: If a "self-deportation document" incorporates an "admission" that the signatory is not a US citizen, could a US citizen who signs this and later successfully proves his citizenship be guilty of some offense relating to false statements and become the target of a new, ostensibly lawful, detention?

Comment: Upon deportation, why would CBP allow you to try to re-enter the country with the questioned documents?   Would CBP not confiscate the questioned documents?

Comment: @gatorback They wouldn't *just* let you reenter with the same docs.  They'd certainly confiscate them on your way out.  From there, you'd have to make your way to the embassy and acquire new docs, which isn't a trivial task.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor  "Devil's Advocate:"  Is it not the *responsibility* of the DHS CBP to have the capability to recognize authentic documentation?  Is it conceivable that citizens have at least one parent that is not a citizen?   As I understand it, the mother was not present at the stop.   Does the government have the responsible to design a process pathway for US citizens incorrectly detained to be processed in an expeditious manner?

Comment: @gatorback  I think once you grant that border crossing is imperfect that this is the type of story you'd have to come up with for them to make this mistake.  I think the mistake of confusing a natural born citizen for an illegal is being compounded by his being held in bad (an understatement I know) conditions for so long. If you hold the two issues separate then it seems like a pretty reasonable mistake, to me.  I say they're separate issues because he was treated the same as everyone else suspected (or known) to be an illegal crosser.

Comment: If there was  a _reasonable_ suspicion, that Francisco Erwin Galicia was in possession of forged documents, why is it stated that "ICE was illegally or irrationally detaining him"?

Comment: @MichaelJ. Because ICE's entire process is irrational and borderline illegal.

Comment: @TRiG  Nothing in this post or the referenced news story seems to support your opinion.  Even if I stipulated that the U.S. Immigration and Customs Enforcement Agency is generally corrupt, _in this case_  they have done nothing that is irrational or illegal.

Comment: @MichaelJ. Searching without a warrant is illegal. So I'm pretty sure the checkpoint was at least legally sketchy.

Comment: @Tezra Search in general is not illegal without a warrant. _Unreasonable search or seizure_ is illegal without a warrant. Granted, arguments could certainly be made that the checkpoints constitute unreasonable search, but courts have ruled otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelJ. If I may play devil's advocate: In the course of evaluating actions of authorities: What is a reasonable amount of time to be held in detention for DHS to determine authenticity of documentation: hours, days, weeks?   We will have to leave it to the judges in the courts decide if the actions were legal / irrational: as I understand there is talk of a lawsuit

Comment: @Will I suspect that (1) yes a citizen participating in a self-deportation would be breaking the law; and (2) there are federal officials willing to vigorously prosecute this crime while overlooking the crimes committed by ICE agents.  If I were a juror, I would probably decline to convict even if I was convinced the self-deporter "broke the law" but others might choose to convict.

Comment: @gatorback there is a process.  It is called "DO NOT TALK TO THE POLICE".  At an inland border checkpoint:  do not answer any questions and do not show any documents.  As I understand it, this whole thing happened because CBP "found a defect" in one of Galicia's documents.  This is not to blame Galicia but to offer advise.  If they don't see the documents, they can not "find the defect."  IANAL

Comment: @MichaelJ. At some point in the three weeks, whatever reasonable suspicion they had ceased to be reasonable. If it had truly been reasonable, they would have described their reasonable suspicion instead of falsely claiming that he never asserted US citizenship.  While they have disclosed facts that make some suspicion reasonable, they have not explained why they held him for so long.  Also, for a criminal arrest, the standard is probable cause.  They have an obligation to establish probable cause by investigating their suspicion.  Whether the investigation was sufficient is not apparent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96867/discussion-on-answer-by-bluedogranch-self-deportation-of-american-citizens-from).

Comment: @reirab unreasonable search and seizure are illegal, period.  If a warrant has been unreasonably granted, the warrant is illegal.  If there is a reasonably granted warrant but the search is nonetheless unreasonable, it is illegal.  If there is no warrant but the search is nonetheless reasonable, it is legal.  The meaning of "reasonable" depends on the circumstances.